# How to write a sortRemove method for MaxHeapPriorityQueue in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, heap, priority-queue, heapsort

I am working on a helper method private E sortRemove(), for my HeapSort static method. Let me note, that this heap is a MaxHeapPriorityQueue, which all the elements have a child that has a value that is smaller than the parent.

I am trying to

- Call remove repeatedly until the heap is empty.
- But make it so that when an element is "removed", it is moved to the end of the array instead of completely evicted from the array.
- When you are done, voila!  The array is sorted.

I'm trying to figure out how to have this algorithm fit into my code.

Therefore I have :

```
public class MaxHeapPriorityQueue<E extends Comparable<E>>
{
private E[] elementData;
private int size;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public MaxHeapPriorityQueue()
{
    elementData = (E[]) new Comparable[10];
    size = 0;
}
public static void heapSort(Comparable[] a, int size)
{
    MaxHeapPriorityQueue mhpq = new MaxHeapPriorityQueue();
    mhpq.elementData = a;
    mhpq.size = size;

    for (int i = (size/2)-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        mhpq.bubbleDown(i);
    }
    for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        a[i] = mhpq.sortRemove();
    }
}
private E sortRemove()
{
    for (int i = (size-1)/2; i >= 0; i--)  //down to 0
    {
        bubbleDown(i);
    }
    while(size > 0)
    {
        swap(elementData, size, 0); // puts the largest item at the end of the heap
        size = size - 1;          // decrease remaining count
        bubbleDown(0);    // adjust the heap
    }
    return sortRemove();
}
}
```

I know this isn't necessarily the correct algorithm, but from my understanding, I want to get the first value which is the largest, to be the last element in the list that way it is sorted. The HeapSort method isn't necessarily accurate either, therefore, I have another question addressing that ([How to create a HeapSort method to an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56095187/how-to-create-a-heapsort-method-to-an-array-in-java)), in this one, I want to primarily focus on the sortRemove method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with

We store that original value somewhere for it to be saved.

Then change the first value index to be the last and decrement the size.

Then we bubble down at only index 0.

Then we return the value.

```
private E sortRemove()
{
    E value = elementData[0];
    elementData[0] = elementData[size-1];
    size--;
    bubbleDown(0);
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An in-place heap sort consists of two steps:

1. Creating a heap from an arbitrary array.
2. Rearranging the resulting array so that it's sorted.

You can do the first step in O(n) time by employing the `makeHeap` algorithm. I show the basic idea below. Assume an array `a` with length `n`.

```
for i = (n-1)/2 downto 0
    bubbleDown(i);
```

Note that you start in the middle and work your way back towards the beginning of the array. Let me give you an example of how it works. Say you're given the array `[1,5,3,4,6,7,2]`. Represented as a binary heap, that becomes:

```
        1
    5       3
 4    6   7   2
```

`(n-1)/2` is 3, so we start with the value `4` in the heap. That can't move, so we go to the value `3`. We're building a max heap, so we check the two children to see if either is larger than 3. If so, we swap with the largest of the two children. That gives:

```
        1
    5       7
 4    6   3   2
```

Moving backwards to the value `5`, we see that `6` is greater, and so we swap those two items:

```
        1
    6       7
 4    5   3   2
```

And, finally, the root element. `7` is the larger of the children, so we swap:

```
        7
    6       1
 4    5   3   2
```

And since we haven't reached the leaf level yet, we check again and swap `1` with `3`:

```
        7
    6       3
 4    5   1   2
```

And there you have a valid max heap. This algorithm *always* works.

Note that your idea of starting at the root and working down won't always result in a valid heap. Take the starting position I gave earlier:

```
        1
    5       3
 4    6   7   2
```

If I start at the top and bubble down, then we swap `1` and `5`, and then we swap `5` and `6`, giving:

```
        6
    5       3
 4    1   7   2
```

We look at 5 and it doesn't need to be bubbled down. Then we look at `3` and we swap with `7`, resulting in:

```
        6
    5       7
 4    1   3   2
```

And you're done because the leaf level can't be bubbled down. And you end up with a tree that is not a valid heap.

So, `makeHeap` to build the heap.

Step 2: sorting.

Sorting the array once you've created a heap is pretty easy. The basic algorithm is:

```
while n > 0
    swap(a[0], a[n-1]) // puts the largest item at the end of the heap
    n = n - 1          // decrease remaining count
    bubbleDown(0)      // adjust the heap
```

This is just a slight modification of the standard `removeLargest` function from any max heap implementation. Rather than removing and returning the root item, you're swapping it with the last item in the heap.

Let's take a look at how that works. Given the starting heap:

```
        7
    6       3
 4    5   1   2
```

Swap 7 with 2, reduce the count, and bubble down:

```
        6
    5       3
 4    2   1   7
```

Swap 6 with 1, reduce the count, and bubble down:

```
        5
    4       3
 1    2   6   7
```

Swap 5 with 2, reduce the count, and bubble down:

```
        4
    2       3
 1    5   6   7
```

Swap 4 with 1, reduce the count, and bubble down:

```
        3
    2       1
 4    5   6   7
```

... And I'll stop there 'cause I think you get the idea.

It really is as simple as that. If you have a max heap implementation with `insert` and `removeLargest` methods, and the standard `siftUp` and `bubbleDown` (or whatever you call them) helper methods, then adding a sorting method is a matter of creating those two small functions that call the helper methods.

Suggested `heapSort` method:

```
public static void heapSort(Comparable[] a, int size)
{
  MaxHeapPriorityQueue elementData = new MaxHeapPriorityQueue();
  // PriorityQueue<Comparable> pq = new PriorityQueue();

  for (int i = (size-1)/2; i >= 0; i--)  //down to 0
  {
    bubbleDown(i);
  }
  while(size > 0)
  {
    swap(elementData, size, 0); // puts the largest item at the end of the heap
    size = size - 1;          // decrease remaining count
    bubbleDown(0);    // adjust the heap
  }
  // The array is sorted.
}
```

Comment: Let me just add, that in my swap method, I have two indexes, how could I swap them when I have two indexes? would you like for me to provide the code for that method?

Comment: And essentially, what would I return considering that it has to be a value of generic E?

Comment: Can I return the method itself?

Comment: @AdanVivero So change my pseudo-code `swap` to `swap(a, 0, n-1)`. That appears to match the semantics of your `swap` method. As far as what to return, I don't understand the question. See my update for a suggested implementation of the `heapSort` method. Note that this is untested code, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: I believe I found my answer already in the sortRemove() method.