# How to write a bubbleDown method with Heap in Java?

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue, bubble-sort, heapsort

I know there are several questions like this posted all over stack overflow, however none really answer my question. I am writing a helper private bubbleDown method to help me sort on my public static HeapSort method.

I know the Idea is to Treat a itself as a max-heap, whose data starts at 0 (not 1).

- a is not actually in heap order.
- But if you repeatedly "bubble down" each non-leaf node, starting from the last one, you will eventually have a proper heap.

I've written this algorithm, however I'm not sure if this exactly works.

```
public class MaxHeapPriorityQueue<E extends Comparable<E>>
{
private E[] elementData;
private int size;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public MaxHeapPriorityQueue()
{
    elementData = (E[]) new Comparable[10];
    size = 0;
}
public static void heapSort(Comparable[] a, int size)
{
    MaxHeapPriorityQueue mhpq = new MaxHeapPriorityQueue();
    mhpq.elementData = a;
    mhpq.size = size;
    for (Comparable n : a)
    {
        mhpq.bubbleDown((int) n);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++)
    {
        a[i] = mhpq.sortRemove();
    }
}
private void bubbleDown(int index)
{
    boolean found = false;
    while(!found)
    {
        int leftIndex = lChild(index);
        int rightIndex = rightChild(index);
        int largestChildIndex = leftIndex;

        if(hasRChild(index))
        {

     if(elementData[leftIndex].compareTo(elementData[rightIndex]) < 0 )
     {
        largestChildIndex = rightIndex;
     }
}
        if(hasLChild(index))
        {

   if(elementData[largestChildIndex].compareTo(elementData[index]) > 0)
            {
                swap(elementData, largestChildIndex , index);
                index = largestChildIndex;
            }
            else
            {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        else //Probably a leaf
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now everything seems to running more smoothly, it's just when I have duplicate values, they are not ordered correctly. I am failing to find this error in my bubble method.

Comment: This question also links up with my other two previous questions that I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56095187/how-to-create-a-heapsort-method-to-an-array-in-java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119836/how-to-write-a-sortremove-method-for-maxheappriorityqueue-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I got

```
private void bubbleDown(int index)
{
    boolean found = false;
    while(!found && (2*index +1) < size)
    {
        int left = leftChild(index) + 1;
        int right = rightChild(index) + 1;
        int child = left;

        if((index*2 +2) < size && elementData[right].compareTo(elementData[left]) > 0)
        {
            child = right;
        }
        if(elementData[index].compareTo(elementData[child]) < 0)
        {
            swap(elementData, index, child);
            index = child;
        }
        else
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }
}
```